# How do you listen to events emitted by the root element in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, events, vuejs2, event-listener

I am very new to Vue.js, but understand how events emitted by child components are listened to by their parent components.

However, I am using a plugin (vue-masonry) and this plugin causes event to be emitted on the Root element, which I can see in the events tab of Vue Devtools. with  as the source. How would I listen to these events, either on a relevant component or globally? I am not sure if this is even possible, or if it is implemented in a way such that the events are only listenable internally by the plugin. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/shershen08/vue-masonry/blob/master/src/masonry.plugin.js). The events in question are the 4 events named like `${EVENT_ADD}__${masonryId}`;

I have tried listening to the event like this when creating the root instance of my app:

```
new Vue({
        el: '#explore-app',
        data: {
            function() {
                return {}
            }
        },
        render: h => h(explore)
    })
    .$on('eventName', (event) => {console.log('Handle event')}).
;
```

And have also tried the following in the created() method of a component:

```
created() {
    this.$root.$on('eventName', (event) => {console.log('Handle event')});
}
```

Neither of these methods have any effect - nothing appears on the console. Is there any way I can listen to these the events emitted by the Root element?

Comment: Looking at `vue-masonry` I am not sure if it really emits to the root: I assume you mean events like this: `Events.$emit(`${EVENT_IMAGE_LOADED}__${masonryId}`, {...` right? A may be wrong, but if it was to emit to root it would be something like: `this.$root.$emit` no? So I assume that your wrapping component where you use `v-masonry` should receive those events. Have you tried to listen to the events within the wrapping component?

Comment: If you then have to escalate the events to other components which are in another relation than `parent - child` I would suggest you have a look at vuex (https://vuex.vuejs.org/) where you can save your apps state in a store, where other components can register properties and act on change. 
I hope that this helps, also I would be interested what you find out about the masonry, event-bus-thing :)

Comment: @Merc It looks like the plugin is using a sepaate Vue instance just for handling events (const Events = new Vue({}) which is unrelated to my actual app. So the Root element the events are being fired is not actually the root of my app. It is a 3rd party plugin so I can't start making it use Vuex. However, I have realised I can do what I want to do without listening to the events at all, so it is academic now.

Comment: Alright. I see. I did see that new Vue, but I thought that would not really make sense to initialize a vue instance in another vue app, so I thought that was doing something else. But interesting . Thanks for sharing.